# Search for status of question

Tags: feature-request, search

Is there no way to search for `closed` or `protected` (for instance) posts?

Something like gmail's `is:` keyword would seem like a good fit, should I not be wrong, and the idea considered.

**EDIT** Michael Petrotta has pointed me to the advanced search page which shows the syntax for searching for `closed` questions, but I don't see anyway of searching for `protected` questions.

Comment: Do a search, then click `Advanced search tips` on the right hand side of the page.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - Thanks, edited my question while I couldn't get to the search page. Deleted after I realised that `Closed:yes` is already there (Though think this would read better as being `is:closed`. However, don't see any way to search for (for instance) protected questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you visit the [dedicated search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), you'll find a full list of supported search parameters. Click the "Advanced Search Tips" link.

I won't list them all here, because I don't want to trap the list in amber when it might change. But I see, among the two dozen-ish options, the ability to search for closed, but not protected, questions.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Didn't realise, but for the second time tonight I cannot get to this page (http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/search) :(

Comment: @user66001: Yeah, there's intermittent something-something going on. I saw it too. Try again now.