# Search for protected questions

Tags: feature-request, search, protected-questions

With reference to this question 
[Search for status of question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163645/search-for-status-of-question) and 
[Can we have a "isprotected" search operator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/can-we-have-a-isprotected-search-operator?rq=1)

Can be bring a feature to search for protected questions ?

Why ??

Most of the protected questions are one of the best questions ever and highly knowledgeable ones.

Few Examples

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547778/why-is-one-loop-so-much-slower-than-two-loops/8547993#8547993)

If there can be a search for closed questions then why not a search for protected question ?

Comment: @downvoter Any comments to improve my question ??

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good idea, but I doubt its usefulness. Think of it this way: If you search for "[php] [jquery]" you will get questions tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). But protected questions aren't really a group on their own. Unlike closing questions, **protecting a question is subjective and can be done for any of several reasons**.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17849074/1234256), for example, I flagged for protection because it had already attracted three "thanks" answers in a short period of time. This isn't an especially good question, but it attracted bad answers. There are other protected questions that *are*, in fact, very good questions with very good answers. I would instead recommend using `is:answer score:500` (or so) if you're just looking for those. (The answers to which you linked had 14k and 950 upvotes, respectively.)

Comment: Agree ! But most of the questions which are protected do really have good answers in them compared to those who have attracted "thanks" answers.

Comment: `If there can be a search for closed questions then why not a search for protected question ?`

Comment: @Javageek Not sure I'd say "most", but `is:answer score:500` will find them.